# CheckBox Tree Item hide borders

Tags: checkbox, javafx-2

Does anybody know if it is possibile, and how to, hide or do not show CheckBoxTreeItem borders?

I mean the rectangle such as this picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setStyle()` method with the `-fx-border-color` property.

```
    treeView.setStyle("-fx-border-color: white white white white;");
```

(`null` instead of `white` seems to work too)

Comment: Thanks Marc, to me it works only with white and not with null. Borders still appears when one of the checkboxes are selected or clicked

Comment: @Albertoacepsut maybe transparent will do a better job than null